# ImportError: libkea.so.1.4.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, conda, osmnx

I am installing package OSMnx following this link: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/ on Linux using 
`conda install -c conda-forge osmnx`.
It works, but with a warning like this:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.5.12

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

So I update the conda, and re-install the OSMnx package again in my computer. After that, I start my Python shell and entered `import osmnx` to test it. Then I got the following error.

```
Python 3.7.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 13 2018, 18:33:04) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import osmnx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .buildings import *
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/buildings.py", line 9, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import read_file
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "/home/devel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: libkea.so.1.4.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After searching, I found this link: https://github.com/darribas/contextily/issues/42 But it's not easy for me to understand what's going on. Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: Maybe you have a broken version of the module that is missing files

Comment: Really? how to solve this then? this module looks mature. So I thought it should be good.

Comment: I am not completely sure, I don't specialize in this

Answer (score 3):

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation): "If you have any trouble with the installation, try installing OSMnx in a new, clean virtual environment using conda and conda-forge":

```
conda create --override-channels -c conda-forge -n OSMNX python=3 osmnx
```

This should resolve Fiona (dependency) installation/path issues.

Comment: For anyone running into the same issues trying to install rasterio and gdal, this solved the problem as well.